# Get Host of HttpResponseMessage in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App (C#) where I am sending a HttpRequest and I want to check if the response I am getting is from a Captive/Limited Access Network or from the actual host specified in the HttpRequest.

So lets say I am sending a request to www.serverA.com
I look at the response of that request and determine if it was success based on the status code.

Imagine the same scenario in a captive network(airport networks/starbucks where they redirect you to a login page):

- I am sending a request to www.serverA.com
- My request gets redirected
  to www.serverB.com/AirPortLoginPage
- I get back a response that the
  AirportLoginPage loaded successfully with a 200 response
- My code sees that as a success because of the 200 status code, but I wanted to know if my original request was successful

So, is there a way to determine the host of the server where the Response Message is coming from?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "Captive/Limited Access Network", but let me ask - do you want to know if your request was transferred or not (like with 302 redirection)?

Comment: I made the question more clear, hopefully ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two things which can solve your problem:

1. You can set [HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect.aspx/html) property to
   `false`. But if any other code depends on this - you will need to
   handle 3xx (redirect) manually.
2. You can check [HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.requestmessage.aspx). In your example after you will send request to `www.serverA.com` - this property will have `www.serverB.com/AirPortLoginPage`